# Hosting multiple sub-domains from a single aws s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hosting, amazon-route53

Is it possible to host multiple subdomains from a single bucket folders?

Example -

Lets assume **bucketname** is my aws s3 bucket. 
To access the site url is - **http://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com**.

Now lets assume i have 5 folders inside it - a,b,c,d & e.

Can i create subdomains pointing to their respective folders inside the s3 bucket. Like -

- **http://a.bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com** site works from folder a of the bucket
- **http://b.bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com** site works from folder b of the bucket
- **http://c.bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com** site works from folder c of the bucket
  and so on.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 alone cannot do what you ask for.

The URL will point to only **one bucket**.

Typically, however, people want a **Custom URL** to point to content. For example, you could point `mycompanyname.com` to Amazon S3. This involves:

- Owning the domain name
- Creating a bucket with a name that matches the domain name (thus, you'd need one bucket per domain/subdomain)
- Configuring the DNS entry (in Amazon Route 53 or your own DNS provider) to with a CNAME that points to the S3 bucket

Alternatively, behaviours can be configured in **Amazon CloudFront** that can present content from various back-ends.

Answer (score 0):

Naming conventions for bucket URL are fixed by AWS. You cannot change to subdomain URL. You can use CloudFront to host it in your own domain or it can host under *.cloudfront.net.

Subdomain for cloudfront is also random. Will look like the following.

> d3v7q0dqls688r.cloudfront.net

Hope it helps.